# How to set table column value using value from column in another table during select

Tags: java, mysql

I have three tables.

Results table:

```
|result_id|client_id|....|inmylist (boolean)|
|rs_1     |cli_1    |....|null              |
|rs_2     |cli_1    |....|null              |
|rs_3     |cli_2    |....|null              |
|rs_4     |cli_3    |....|null              |
|rs_5     |cli_2    |....|null              |
|rs_6     |cli_1    |....|null              |
```

Mylist table:

```
|list_id|listname|list_description|
|1      |list one|first list desc |
|2      |list two|high performers |
|3      |list bla|lazy managers ..|
```

list_results table:

```
|list_id|result_id|
|1      |rs_1     |
|1      |rs_2     |
|2      |rs_1     |
|2      |rs_5     |
```

The inmylist column in results table is null by default, its value will be dynamically set during select, depending if the results exists in list_results table.
i.e.

Selecting all results with client_id = cli_1 and list_id = 1 should return:

```
|result_id|client_id|....|inmylist (boolean)|
|rs_1     |cli_1    |....|true              |
|rs_2     |cli_1    |....|true              |
|rs_6     |cli_1    |....|false             |
```

Selecting all results with client_id = cli_2 and list_id = 2 should return:

```
|result_id|client_id|....|inmylist (boolean)|
|rs_3     |cli_2    |....|false             |
|rs_5     |cli_2    |....|true              |
```

Currently I do programatically by doing a first query and then do another query to get all items in the list with list_id, then iterate in the previous result and change the value of inmylist.

I think this is not a very efficient way, If there is a way to achieve this from query and avoid the round trip as well as iteration. When the size of the tables grows the performance starts to suffer.

So please advice me on how to achieve this by mysql queries only.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You should use CASE WHEN (condition) THEN ... [ELSE] END CASE inline, in your SELECT statement.

For instance:

```
SELECT a.col1, a.col2, b.col1, CASE a.col1 == "X" THEN 'True!' ELSE 'Argh...' END CASE as DerivedColumn FROM a, b;
```

In the example above I "compute"/derive a column (that does not exist, physically, in none of the tables being selected) by using a CASE statement. Depending on the value of column COL1, from table a, for each row being selected, the value is set to either "True!" or "Argh".

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible with something like:

```
UPDATE
  result_table r
SET
  r.inmylist =
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list_result l
   WHERE r.result_id = l.result_id) > 0
```

Comment: You have not understood my question well. Your approach does not solve my problem, it does something completely different. I need to select and use the results in an application, not to update the results table.